# Store data of React in Django Database without using Models

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a simple project in **React** and **Django**. I am a beginner. I am trying to build a punch in machine. I am working on a feature where the user when clicks the image then it displays the time and date she clicked the image. I want to store that time and date in database.But I do not know how to? Do I need to create Model or can be done without the model. My code so far

Index.js

```
function CDate(){
  const dt = null;
  const [cdate,setDate] = useState(dt); 
  const handelDate = () =>{
    let dt = new Date().toLocaleString();
    setDate(dt);
  }

  return(
    <>
      <h3>{cdate}</h3>
      <img src={punchin} alt="PunchinMachine" onClick={handelDate} />
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<CDate />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

*Could you please me store the time she clicked in the db so that I can keep track of time.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but the only way to store data in database is through models, so you must create model. Don't worry, it is not difficult at all:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

Class Register(models.Model):
date = model.DateField(default = datetime.datetime.now())
time = model.DatetimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now())
```

Also, you must define an endpoint to receive the data and a serializer to serialize the received data through the endpoint. But I won't show you the code of this steps to allow you discover it by yourself.

I recommend you start by the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) , which is excellent as a getting started, specially the part 2, because it is referred to models. And after that you should visit the [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) , which is the de-facto approach to deal with serialization.

**Good luck with the journey !!**

Comment: Hey Ariel ! Thanks for the half answer. I did go through the Django tutorial and Django Rest Framework as you suggested but I am still confuse may be because it is my first time  creating any project from the scratch. It would be great if you could give me the other half answer. In most of the doc and tutorial I could see they create a form which include name, email and created date and sync to DB. But I want is to store the current date and time in Django database. How do I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also I need to store the value of {cdate} to be specific.